# Python WebkitGtk: How to respond to the default context menu items?

Tags: python, gtk, webkit

The default context menu contains items like "Open link in new window" and "Download linked file", which don't seem to do anything. I obviously like to react on these items, but can't figure out how, since the port's documentation is a bit sparse. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the C port, you have to connect to the '`create-web-view`', '`new-window-policy-decision-requested`', and '`download-requested`' signals. I think the Python port works the same way. See this page for the documentation on the C versions of those signals:

http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk-WebKitWebView.html

Comment: Ah, I now see what the problem is. I'm on Ubuntu and libwebkit is still on 1.0.1, whereas the signals I'm looking for were only added in 1.1.4 and 1.1.2. I'll see if I can find a PPA somewhere. Thanks for pointing me into the right direction.